# Python finding subdirectories with pkgutil's extend_path

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

This is my folder structure

```
src
├── __init__.py
└── foo
    ├── __init__.py
    └── bar
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── events
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── execute
        │   │   ├── __init__.py
        │   │   ├── helloworld.py
        │   │   ├── run.py
        └── settings.py
```

`$ cat src/foo/__init__.py` outputs...

```
from pkgutil import extend_path

__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

in `src/foo/bar/events/execute/run.py`, I want to do something like this

```
from foo.bar.events.execute.helloworld import HelloWorld
```

I get the **error**

```
No module named 'foo.bar'
```

This is how I'm running my app

> I understand it's not proper, but there's a reason I just simplified the question for brevity

```
$ python src/foo/bar/events/execute/run
```

How do I achieve importing this way from `src/foo/bar/events/execute/run.py`?

```
from foo.bar.events.execute.helloworld import HelloWorld
```

Comment: I am having same issue, did you find any solution ?